# Count elements in an array of nodes

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a function for collecting entries and zipping them before offering them to users in a form of epub. The problem is I collect every chapter as `<entry/>` element, which means there is no root element. I only have a variable with an array of chapters. Is there any way to solve this?

For example:

```
let $chaps := (
    <entry>
        <html>
            <h1>abc</h1>
            <h2>xxx</h2>
            <h2>yyy</h2>
        </html>
    </entry>,
    <entry>
        <html>
            <h1>def</h1>
            <h2>xxx</h2>
            <h2>yyy</h2>
        </html>
    </entry>,
    <entry>
        <html>
            <h1>ghi</h1>
            <h2>xxx</h2>
            <h2>yyy</h2>
        </html>
    </entry>,
    <entry>
        <html>
            <h1>jkl</h1>
            <h2>xxx</h2>
            <h2>yyy</h2>
        </html>
    </entry>
)
```

I am trying:

```
for $entry in $chaps
return 
    <headings>
        <a>{'Count h1 in preceding entries: ' || count($entry/preceding-sibling::entry//h1)}</a>
        <b>{'Count h2 in preceding entries: ' || count($entry/preceding-sibling::entry//h2)}</b>
    </headings>
```

The results:

```
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 0</a>
    <b>Count h2 in preceding entries: 0</b>
</headings>
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 0</a>
    <b>Count h2 in preceding entries: 0</b>
</headings>
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 0</a>
    <b>Count h2 in preceding entries: 0</b>
</headings>
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 0</a>
    <b>Count h2 in preceding entries: 0</b>
</headings>
```

Expected:

```
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 0</a>
    <b>Count h2 in preceding entries: 0</b>
</headings>
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 1</a>
    <b>Count h2 in preceding entries: 2</b>
</headings>
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 2</a>
    <b>Count h2 in preceding entries: 4</b>
</headings>
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 3</a>
    <b>Count h2 in preceding entries: 6</b>
</headings>
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you also show the desired output that you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I will try to clear that a bit but it is quite simple―I am not able to count all preceding elements. If there is one `h1` and two `h2` elements per entry, how to count all preceding `h1` and `h2`? In the case of iterating over the fourth entry, it could be 3 and 6 but it is not.

Comment: It only counts them for the current entry, the result is always 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because inside the variable there is really an array, it is needed to iterate over the array, not over the variable alone. Finally, this works for me:

```
for $entry at $index in $chaps
return 
    <headings>
        <a>{'Count h1 in preceding entries: ' || count(
                for $i in 1 to $index
                return $entry//xhtml:h1
        )}</a>
        <b>{'Count h1 in preceding entries: ' || count(
                for $i in 1 to $index
                return $entry//xhtml:h2
        )}</b>
    </headings>
```

Result:

```
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 1</a>
    <b>Count h1 in preceding entries: 2</b>
</headings>
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 2</a>
    <b>Count h1 in preceding entries: 4</b>
</headings>
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 3</a>
    <b>Count h1 in preceding entries: 6</b>
</headings>
<headings>
    <a>Count h1 in preceding entries: 4</a>
    <b>Count h1 in preceding entries: 8</b>
</headings>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you then:

```
count($entry//preceding::xhtml:h1)
```

is not producing your expected results, as you want to count `h1` that appear in preceding `entry`?

If so don't use `//` as that means *self-or-descendant*, instead I think you want something like:

```
$entry/preceding-sibling::entry//xhtml:h1
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I guess it will work. I will try tomorrow. Basics, as usually ☺

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. The thing could be the very first element, `entry`, is in no namespace. Inside it there is a proper `xhtml` with its namespace. I have tried `$entry/preceding-sibilng::*[local-name() = 'entry']//xhtml:h1` but it is the same, 0 results. It is very tricky! `$chaps[1]` is the same as the first result in  `for $entry in $chaps return $entry`. It seems if there is not the root element, the context needed for axis-based xpaths is lost, isn't it?

Comment: I think you need to show us better example data and better corresponding expected results, and then I can help you further...

Comment: I have just updated the question. This mimics my scenario and I guess if solved, it could help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler implementation possible using the position() function. I think this is what you were aiming at originally:

```
for $a at $pos in $chaps
return 
<headings>
        <a>{'Count h1 in preceding entries: ' || count($chaps[position() < $pos]//h1)}</a>
        <b>{'Count h2 in preceding entries: ' || count($chaps[position() < $pos]//h2)}</b>
    </headings>
```